# How to reference something in the create statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Basic question, but I want to know how to reference something I have just created. For example, if I create something like this...

```
  EmployeeExpenseClaim.create(employee_id: @employee.id, account_id: @employee.account.id, claim_status: 'In Progress')
```

I then want to call a method on the model to generate a record in the log file.

```
EmployeeExpenseClaim.last.generate_log('Claim created', @employee)
```

Obviously, using the "last" is not correct, so how do I get the id of the instance I have just created. I tried the following but it didn't like it.

```
  c = EmployeeExpenseClaim.create(employee_id: @employee.id, account_id: @employee.account.id, claim_status: 'In Progress')
  c.generate_log('Claim created', @employee)
```

Suspect this will be obvious when someone points it out, so sorry for the newbie question. It all works nicely if I use:

```
c = EmployeeExpenseClaim.new
etc...
```

But I thought it would be more elegant to use the create method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use an after create callback to call the method.